# Can I become leader of the Thieves' Guild without finishing the main chain and is there any benefits from being the leader anyway?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed the quest where you get the Skeleton Key and I don't really want to continue the chain until I've done a lot of the other stuff in the game, since the key is so useful. Brynjolf said before that I would become leader of the guild after everything was over.

Can I become the leader anyway without finishing the Nightingales quest chain? Are there any bonuses for being the leader?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot be named Guildmaster until you resolve your unfinished business with Nocturnal.

Benefits of being named Guild Master include a tribute chest full of (respawning!) loot, the Guild Master armor (an improved version of the Thieves Guild armor you were issued on joining, and a perk giving +25% Armor Rating when wearing a full set of Guild Armor.

Comment: Also, there a couple of quests you can only receive after becoming Guild Master. The most important is bartering with the Caravan network, which essentially places a bunch of traveling fences at your disposal.

Comment: You can connect with the caravans without becoming guild master - you merely need to regain respect in all 5 major Hold Cities.

Comment: cool :) I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: fyi The guild master armor is bugged (I forgot where I read that), so you will lose the light armor perk that gives you a rating boost when wearing all light armor